# The twilio iOS SDK for conversations doesn't surface errors to the delegate

Tags: ios, twilio, twilio-conversations

I am not getting any errors surfacing from the `TwilioConversationsClientDelegate`

```
public func conversationsClient(_ client: TwilioConversationsClient, errorReceived error: TCHError)
```

The errors do show up in the console when the log level is set to `.debug` They just aren't surfacing in either the completionhandler for api calls, nor the above delegate function.

Specifically the errors Im concerned about are connection errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This delegate method is calling on client's issues only. For instance, if client could not be initialized, updating token failed or registering for notifications went wrong.

Are you expecting to see these errors in this delegate method?

Comment: Either in the completion handler or the delegate - I would assume connection errors specifically would be handled by the delegate since thats what the documentation says. The main issue is that connection errors aren't being surfaced anywhere - but are logged in the console.

Comment: @MweyaMutsvene What is the version of SDK you are using?

Comment: I am using the latest 1.2.0

Comment: We are investigating this issue, we will prepare a fix for that ASAP.

Comment: We've released version 1.3.0 with fixes related to this issue, could you check it?